# Setting a conditional kernel breakpoint in WinDbg grinds the debuggee OS to a halt

Tags: windbg, breakpoint, kernel-mode

My setup:

- Debugger: Win10 Pro, WinDbg Preview v.1.0.1904.18001
- Debuggee: Win7 Pro (running in a VM using VMWare Workstation)

I'm trying to follow the `SendMessage` call from the user space:

[image]

Into the kernel, by setting a conditional breakpoint on `win32k!NtUserMessageCall`:

[image]

If we take the declaration of the `NtUserMessageCall` function:

```
NTSTATUS NtUserMessageCall(
    HWND hWnd,
    UINT uMsg,
    WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam,
    ULONG_PTR ResultInfo,
    DWORD dwWndProcType,
    BOOL bAnsi);
```

The condition for the breakpoint is for `uMsg == WM_SYSCOMMAND` (or 0x112). I set it as such:

```
ba e 1 fffff960`00163318 "j (@rdx=0x112) ''; 'gc'"
```

I can then check that it was set up alright:

[image]

But when I then "Go" the OS:

[image]

The debuggee OS literally grinds to a halt. I can't do anything. I can see some "life" in there by seeing the clock widget jumping by 20 second intervals but it is impossible to interact with windows or do anything. Note that if I disable the breakpoint above, everything starts working smoothly.

Can someone explain what am I doing wrong there? And how can I make it work?

Comment: If you can't do anything how you disable the breakpoint? I think you will have to run the OS in sort of virtual machine and debug that....

Comment: @Ricardo: The debuggee OS is running in a virtual machine. (The first screenshot is from a debuggee. It's showing a user-mode IDA. I added it to show that the execution was a few commands away from entering the kernel mode.)

Comment: make sure you are comparing not assigning  with a double == instead of single = use process specifc breakpoint with /p switch (it is a very hot path ) evaluating conditionals is a very intensive work

Comment: @blabb: hmm, that might be an idea. So how would I get the addr of EPROCESS by PID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure how you can do it with ida as front end  shown below is a pure windbg demo

finding _EPROCESS with name or Cid

```
1: kd> !process 0 0 explorer.exe
PROCESS ffff8e0c835c9300
    SessionId: 1  Cid: 0fc8    Peb: 00583000  ParentCid: 0f8c
    DirBase: 0a600002  ObjectTable: ffffd58bc24b0d40  HandleCount: 1913.
    Image: explorer.exe

1: kd> !process 0fc8 0
Searching for Process with Cid == fc8
PROCESS ffff8e0c835c9300
    SessionId: 1  Cid: 0fc8    Peb: 00583000  ParentCid: 0f8c
    DirBase: 0a600002  ObjectTable: ffffd58bc24b0d40  HandleCount: 1913.
    Image: explorer.exe
```

setting an unconditional process specific software bp

```
1: kd> bp /p ffff8e0c835c9300 win32kfull!NtUserMessageCall
WARNING: Software breakpoints on session addresses can cause bugchecks.
Use hardware execution breakpoints (ba e) if possible.

1: kd> g
Breakpoint 0 hit
win32kfull!NtUserMessageCall:
ffffeae2`57cdc020 48895c2408      mov     qword ptr [rsp+8],rbx

0: kd> ? @$proc
Evaluate expression: -125290582076672 = ffff8e0c`835c9300

0: kd> kb
 # RetAddr            Call Site
00 fffff803`2abdb285  win32kfull!NtUserMessageCall
01 00007ffc`bb641184  nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x25
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

0: kd> r rdx
rdx=0000000000000081
```

setting a conditional process specific breakpoint

```
0: kd> bp /p ffff8e0c835c9300 win32kfull!NtUserMessageCall ".if (@rdx != 0x112 ) { gc;}"

WARNING: Software breakpoints on session addresses can cause bugchecks.
Use hardware execution breakpoints (ba e) if possible.
breakpoint 0 redefined

0: kd> bl
     0 e Disable Clear  ffffeae2`57cdc020  win32kfull!NtUserMessageCall ".if (@rdx != 0x112 ) {gc;}"
     Match process data ffff8e0c`835c9300


0: kd> g

win32kfull!NtUserMessageCall:
ffffeae2`57cdc020 48895c2408      mov     qword ptr [rsp+8],rbx

1: kd> ? @$proc
Evaluate expression: -125290582076672 = ffff8e0c`835c9300

1: kd> r rdx
rdx=0000000000000112
```

call stack for break

```
1: kd> kb
 # RetAddr             Call Site
00 fffff803`2abdb285   win32kfull!NtUserMessageCall
01 00007ffc`bb641184   nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x25
02 00007ffc`bb8b9d60   win32u!NtUserMessageCall+0x14
03 00007ffc`bb8b98d2   USER32!RealDefWindowProcWorker+0x150
04 00007ffc`b8aeea12   USER32!RealDefWindowProcW+0x52
05 00007ffc`b8aeeaf2   UxTheme!DoMsgDefault+0x2e [es\uxtheme\handlers.cpp @ 550] 
06 00007ffc`b8ae8626   UxTheme!OnDwpSysCommand+0x32 [es\uxtheme\nctheme.cpp @ 7566] 
07 00007ffc`b8ae7641   UxTheme!_ThemeDefWindowProc+0x4c6 [emes\uxtheme\sethook.cpp @ 1067] 
08 00007ffc`bb8b9ad4   UxTheme!ThemeDefWindowProcW+0x11 [hemes\uxtheme\sethook.cpp @ 1109] 
09 00007ffc`a339bd0c   USER32!DefWindowProcW+0x1c4
0a 00007ffc`a33b0f2e   v_WndProc+0xac
0b 00007ffc`bb8bca66   s_WndProc+0x6e
0c 00007ffc`bb8bc78c   USER32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x266
0d 00007ffc`bb8cfa83   USER32!DispatchClientMessage+0x9c
0e 00007ffc`be5322c4   USER32!_fnDWORD+0x33
0f 00007ffc`bb641184   ntdll!KiUserCallbackDispatcherContinue
10 00007ffc`bb8b9d60   win32u!NtUserMessageCall+0x14
11 00007ffc`bb8b98d2   USER32!RealDefWindowProcWorker+0x150
12 00007ffc`b8aeea12   USER32!RealDefWindowProcW+0x52
13 00007ffc`b8aeebb4   UxTheme!DoMsgDefault+0x2e [hemes\uxtheme\handlers.cpp @ 550] 
14 00007ffc`b8ae8626   UxTheme!OnDwpNcLButtonDown+0xa4 [hemes\uxtheme\nctheme.cpp @ 7157] 
15 00007ffc`b8ae7641   UxTheme!_ThemeDefWindowProc+0x4c6 [\themes\uxtheme\sethook.cpp @ 1067] 
16 00007ffc`bb8b9ad4   UxTheme!ThemeDefWindowProcW+0x11 [l\themes\uxtheme\sethook.cpp @ 1109] 
17 00007ffc`a339bd0c   USER32!DefWindowProcW+0x1c4
18 00007ffc`a33b0f2e   v_WndProc+0xac
19 00007ffc`bb8bca66   s_WndProc+0x6e
1a 00007ffc`bb8bc582   USER32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x266
1b 00007ffc`a33a48a3   USER32!DispatchMessageWorker+0x1b2
1c 00007ffc`a33a47a9   FrameMessagePump+0xe3
1d 00007ffc`a33a46f6   explorerframe!BrowserThreadProc+0x85
1e 00007ffc`a33a5a12   explorerframe!BrowserNewThreadProc+0x3a
1f 00007ffc`a33b70c2  InternalResumeRT+0x12
20 00007ffc`babdb3ec  Run+0xb2
21 00007ffc`babdb0a5  TT_Run+0x3c
22 00007ffc`babdaf85  ThreadProc+0xdd
23 00007ffc`bc9ac315  s_ThreadProc+0x35
24 00007ffc`bb6d7e94   shcore!_WrapperThreadProc+0xf5
25 00007ffc`be4f7ad1   KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
26 00000000`00000000   ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21
```

there  isn't any special reason to use software bp  it comes by rote

how to do multiple conditions

```
1: kd> bp win32kfull!NtUserMessageCall ".if ( ( @rdx != 410 ) & ( @rcx != 20498 ) ) { r rdx,rcx; gc }"
WARNING: Software breakpoints on session addresses can cause bugchecks.
Use hardware execution breakpoints (ba e) if possible.
breakpoint 0 redefined
1: kd> g
rdx=0000000000000084 rcx=0000000000010404
rdx=0000000000000084 rcx=000000000001046e
rdx=0000000000000084 rcx=0000000000010404
rdx=0000000000000020 rcx=0000000000010470
rdx=0000000000000020 rcx=000000000001046e
rdx=0000000000000020 rcx=00000000000104a6
rdx=0000000000000020 rcx=000000000001048e
rdx=0000000000000020 rcx=0000000000060480
rdx=0000000000000020 rcx=0000000000010446
rdx=0000000000000020 rcx=0000000000010404
rdx=0000000000000407 rcx=000000000001047c
rdx=0000000000000084 rcx=0000000000010404
rdx=000000000000004e rcx=0000000000010492
win32kfull!NtUserMessageCall:
ffffeae2`57cdc020 48895c2408      mov     qword ptr [rsp+8],rbx
1: kd> r rdx,rcx
rdx=0000000000000407 rcx=0000000000020498
```

demo for bitwise versus logical operators and why logical operator needs to be evaluated as c++

```
0:000> $$ display rdx and rcx register
0:000> r rdx, rcx
rdx=0000000000000000 rcx=00007ffd7a57fc04
0:000> $$ evaluating logical operator as C++ expression
0:000> ?? @rdx && @rcx
bool false
0:000> $$ evaluating logical operator as masm expression (will fail)
0:000> ? @rdx && @rcx
Numeric expression missing from '& @rcx'
0:000> $$ evaluating bitwise operator as masm expression 
0:000> ? @rdx & @rcx
Evaluate expression: 0 = 00000000`00000000
0:000> $$ evaluating bitwise operator as c++ expression 
0:000> ?? @rdx & @rcx
unsigned int64 0
```

Comment: Thanks. Two quick questions. 1) Why are you using software breakpoint instead of a hardware one? and 2) if I want to set up an AND condition, when I did `ba e 1 /p ffffe001ab2c4180 fffff960`00218ac0 ".if (@rdx != 0x112 || @rcx != 0x103cc) {gc;}"` it triggered the breakpoint but not when I expected. RDX was not 0x112 and RCX was not 0x103cc. Is there another syntax for the OR/AND operator?

Comment: no special reason  what are you trying bitwise OR (|) or  logical OR (||) anyway I added an edit take a look

Comment: I'm sorry, but what does `if( @rdx != 410 ) & ( @rcx != 20498 )` do? If the `&` means `AND` then it's as if you wrote `if(true)`. Also can you explain what's the purpose of `r rdx,rcx` part? As for the software bp it may cause BSOD if the memory is not paged yet. That's why I asked.

Comment: & is bitwise && is logical  & is masm operator && is c++ operator  so if your default expression evaluator is masm && will  err and break  you need to enclose the condition with a @@c++ qualifier  that is why i asked what are you trying